# I am getting a error in flutter that method "+" was called on null

Tags: android-studio, flutter

Presently I am playing around with a course on flutter on Udemy with the app named as Personal Expenses

and

I am getting a error in flutter that method "+" was called on null

**Error message :-**

```
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building Chart(dirty):
The method '+' was called on null.
Receiver: null
```

My Code :-

```
import 'package:personal_expenses/models/transaction.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

class Chart extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Transaction> recentTransaction;
  Chart(this.recentTransaction);

  List<Map<String, Object>> get groupedTransactionValues {
    return List.generate(7, (index) {
      final weekDay = DateTime.now().subtract(
        Duration(days: index),
      );
      double totalSum ;

      for (var i = 0; i < recentTransaction.length; i++) {
        if (recentTransaction[i].date.day == weekDay.day &&
            recentTransaction[i].date.month == weekDay.month &&
            recentTransaction[i].date.year == weekDay.year) {
          totalSum += recentTransaction[i].amount;
        }
      }

      return {
        'day': DateFormat.E().format(weekDay).substring(0, 1),
        'amount': totalSum
      };
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      elevation: 6,
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      child: Row(
        children: groupedTransactionValues.map((data) {
          return Text('${data['day']}: ${data['amount']}');
        }).toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it by :-

making the value of totalSum = 0

```
double totalSum = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You were getting that error because you didn't provide any value to your `double` at the time of declaration, and in Dart every field is of type `Object` and by default its value is `null` unlike java where double gets `0` as default value.

```
double totalSum; // default value is null
totalSum += 10; // error, because totalSum is null
```

Solution:

```
 double totalSum = 0; // assign some value
 totalSum += 10; // works
```